# Why are all Ajax methods failing, when the rest of JQuery works

Tags: jquery, ajax, download

I am using Jquery to capture client-side activities.  Everything is good, the code is behavoring as expected until I try to use any AJax method.  None work.  The simplest code snippets...fail.   Any examples I get from the web...fail.   I have tried running the code locally and on a server.   The target file location is ok as I can open it in a browser.  Here is my code

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Loading a Portion of External Page using Ajax in jQuery</title>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                $("#box").load("https://tutorialrepublic.com/examples/html/test-content.html");
            $("p").text("Hello World!");
            });            
        });
       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <h2>Click</h2>
    </div>
      <p>Not loaded yet.</p>
      <button type="button">Load Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing

Comment: Look at the browser console. f12

Comment: Please share more details - "none work" sound like you have tried more than this single piece of code? What do you attempts have in common? And what have you tried to debug them?

Comment: Ultimately I want to retrieve data from a MySQL db.  For now, I would just like to know why this code snippet fails.  I have copied both test-content.html and the code snippet file to the same local folder.  Still, it fails.  I did update the load method to reflect the new file location

Comment: Copied what you have and jquery is working fine. Hello world showed up. But the request to the website failed (check your browser console): "**Cross-Origin Request** Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://tutorialrepublic.com/examples/html/test-content.html. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).". There was also another similar error.

Comment: Also try putting your scripts at the bottom of the page, after your content, before the closing body tag. Link to jquery before your own script (as you are doing).